# Handlebars - Access array by external key in a nested each

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, each

I'm trying to render a table with some labels and corresponding translations.
The translations are passed like this:

```
keys = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "one",
    translations: [
      en: {
        text: "one"
      },
      it: {
        text: "uno"
      },
      es: {
        text: "uno"
      },
      fr: {
        text: "un"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "two",
    translations: [
      es: {
        text: "dos"
      },
      en: {
        text: "two"
      },
      it: null,
      fr: {
        text: "deux"
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

The translations I have to render must be filtered by a simple array like this one:

```
langArray = ["en", "it", "es"];
```

This is how I render the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="background-color:white" id="tblKeys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Key</th>
      {{#each langArray}}
      <th>{{this}}</th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each keys}}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/keys/{{id}}/edit" class=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td>{{label}}</td>
      {{#each ../langArray}}
        {{#if translations[this]}}
          <td>{{translations[this].text}}</td>
        {{else}}
          <td></td>
        {{/if}}  
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is, since `langArray` is used to set the table headers, I need the same order to be respected for the data rows and such is not guaranteed by the incoming data JSON. So I need to iterate over the `keys` and then iterate over `langArray` and get the element in the data JSON having the same index as in the current `langArray` element.

But handlebars doesn't seem to like `translations[this]` nor `translations.this` as another question suggested.

Could some kind soul advice me on this matter?
Thanks in advance for the replies. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by giving distinct references to the two levels and then using a double lookup:

```
  <tbody>
    {{#if rows}}
      {{#each rows as |row|}}
        <tr>
          <td><a href="/keys/{{row.id}}/edit" class=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
          <td>{{row.status}}</td>
          <td>{{row.brand}}</td>
          <td>{{row.type}}</td>
          <td>{{row.label}}</td>
          {{#each ../langArray as |lang|}}
            <td>{{lookup (lookup row.translations lang) 'text'}} </td>
          {{/each}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    {{else}}  
      <tr><td colspan="100" class="text-center">There are no keys to show.</td></tr>
    {{/if}}
  </tbody>
```

Hope this helps someone else! :)